# Is there any way to cache the predefined component imported from library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am making a chat react app. where I have used `emoji-picker-react` library which is providing me `Picker` component. What I am observing while running the app is that component's opening and closing causing some delay. Might be it is using some API calls under the hood.

My question is that can we cache the component in some way to optimize the user experience?

Comment: I think it's slow, because it's fetching a lot of images (for each emoji). `emojiStyle={EmojiStyle.NATIVE}` makes it quicker because it doesn't need to do all the fetching, but you might not like the style. You could also try `lazyLoadEmojis={true}`.